# Trying to use cookies in my react app but can't get them on the server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies

I am switching over to using cookies for a project. Client is react and server is express, using js-cookie and cookie-parser npm packages. On the client the cookie gets set just fine, but on my server when I try to get the cookies nothing is there. Idk if the browser is sending them. I am testing in a firefox browser.

here is where I set them:

```
if (
    action.type === 'user/loginSuccess' ||
    action.type === 'user/signupSuccess'
  ) {
    const currentUser = JSON.stringify(action.payload);
    localStorage.setItem('isAuth', true);
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', currentUser);
    Cookies.set('currentUser', currentUser);
    Cookies.set('isAuth', true);
  }
```

here is how I try to get them:

```
const getAll = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await Product.find({ storeId: req.user.storeId });

    console.log('Cookies:', req.cookies); //is an empty object

    res.status(200).json(products);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json('Server error');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest Using [Node-Localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage) :

```
//import module
import {LocalStorage} from 'node-localstorage' 

// constructor function to create a storage directory inside our project for all our localStorage setItem.
var localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch'); 

//Setting localStorage Item
localStorage.setItem('Name', 'Manish Mandal') 
//console.log localStorage item with the key Name
console.log(localStorage.getItem('Name'))
```